# Вопрос про отбор уникальных записей в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть бд mysql, в ней таблица, в таблице столбик, называется index (знаю, название ужасное), в ячейках находятся записи типа: маша, петя, вася, и т.п., но значения могут повторяться, т.е. они не уникальны. (маша, петя, маша, петя, вася, маша, маша, петя)

Как можно собрать все уникальные записи в массив? (Я так понимаю, нужен запрос, который в цикле перебирает записи, и добавляет в массив.)

Comment: DISTINCT?

    
    SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM table_name

Comment: Или через группировку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вообщем получилось, только не с первого раза. нужно было просто `index` писать в ковычках. буду рад ответу, а не комментарию, чтоб "accept" алепить